# Dart style recommendation on importing local file

Tags: dart

Is there any recommendation how to import local files. In my case I would have 2 options:

1. import 'package:workshop/feed/item.dart';
2. import 'item.dart';

I haven't found anything on that on the guide [Effective Dart: Style](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style) nor on Google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two different recommendations, depending on who you ask.
Either works, I personally recommend the latter, shorter, variant.
It is *sufficient* and it avoids the issue of hard-coding your package name into every file. If you ever want to rename the package, that will be a drudge.

There is one issue which makes some people recommend the former format.
If you import a package library using a non-`package:` URI, say by having a file in the `bin/` or `test/` directory do an import like:

```
import "../lib/mylib.dart";
```

then that library is now imported using two different URIs:

- `package:mypkg/mylib.dart` and
- `file:///somewhere/mypkg/lib/mylib.dart`

Since Dart identifies libraries by their import URIs, these two imports will be treated as different libraries, each with their own global and static variables, which just happen to have the same source code. That's an annoying problem, and can be hard to debug. If you use the long `package:...` import everywhere, then at least the issue is restricted to the *first* library you import. If you use a relative import, `import "src/helper.dart";`, then that library will now also exist in two versions:

- `package:mypkg/src/helper.dart` and
- `file:///somewhere/mypkg/lib/src/helper.dart`

The real issue here was the first import which contained a `/lib/` in the path. You must never have such an import. Using `package:` URIs for all imports may reduce the issue, but not remove it.

I recommend using the relative path, and making sure that you never have a `/lib/` in any import path. Libraries in the `/lib/` directory of a pub package are *package* libraries and should be referred to using `package:` URIs. If you do that, then relative URIs will be resolved against the package URI and again be a package URI, and all is well.

Comment: I love the later too. But do you konw how to avoid vscode autoimport add the `package` prefix?